# faster way to count on indexed field

Tags: mongodb

My collection is pretty huge:

```
 mongos> db.a.count({})
 1711092178
```

( this total count as expected  is executed immediately( is reading the data from the collection meta stats )  )

But attempting to count based on indexed field is taking hours:

```
 mongos>db.a.count({_type:"test"})
```

Please, advice if any faster option to take count of documents based on certain indexed value ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `explain` to see what it is doing, like `db.a.explain(true).count({type:"test"})`

Comment: thanks for the tip , I have just identified one of the shards is much more loaded then the others causing the total executionTime to increase significantly